# geodedics equations

Tags: general-relativity

https://en.m.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Foundation_of_the_Generalised_Theory_of_Relativity

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_in_general_relativity

In his 1915 paper Einstein derives the equations of geodedics, he uses the principle of least action and a centain point he uses as (delta)lambda the length of the geodedics and he obtains a result that is correct, but isn't that a geodedic "orthogonal" to the original? 
On Wikipedia the proof starts with (delta)lambda and ends with (delta)tau which are linear elements that pass through the same point, in Einstein's book instead he uses     (delta)s but isn't that "wrong"? He had to use another parameter right? Mathematically nothing is wrong.

Comment: Why exactly is using delta s wrong?

Comment: Because uses delta s for 2 different linear elements which pass for the same point

Comment: And the action becomes different from zero

Comment: I see, thank you for explaining.